# Coreos Clustering Local and Cloud Hosts

Tags: coreos

I want to make a coreos cluster consists of local machines behind one public ip address and coreos hosts on a cloud service like digitalocean.

I am wondering whether this is possible? Since all the local machines will have the same public ip address. If this is possible please let me know how to do this setup.

Thank you

Jake He

Answer (score 1):

1. You can achieve this using DNS since it can hold multiple records for the same domain name. [look here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-dns-round-robin-load-balancing-for-high-availability)
2. You can achieve this using load balancer - create a virtual IP and a pool with all the local IPs of the CoreOS servers - but take into consideration that some load balancers force you to create a single pool and virtual server for each service port you would like to balance. (Such as bigip-api for instance)